# JS data structure for O(1) caching when checking cache keys by value

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I want to create a cache where I have O(1) lookups to its contents, and I lookup keys by value, not by reference. What data structure in JS, if any, would let me accomplish this?

**Requirements:**

1. The keys represent an array of valid JS variables (primitives or objects).
2. Comparison is handled by **value**, not by reference. (If it was reference, we could just use a single Map)

***What I've tried*:**

I was thinking of nested *Maps* following this structure:

```
const resultKey = new Symbol('result'); // Create a unique result key, so we don't accidentally return if a key happens to be called 'result'. 

// Cache is nested maps, not objects.
const cache = {
  [key1]: {
    [key2]: {
      [key3]: {
        [resultKey]: 1234
      }
    }
  }
}

const foo = function cachedFunc(key1, key2, key3); // If these keys match values in the cache, just return the cache value.
```

And this would work fine for O(1) lookups by **reference**, but for value I would still need to iterate the keys at each level, and do a deep equality check.

Any ideas how I can get an O(1) lookup by value?

Comment: If with "*by value*" you mean a deep equality check, you cannot get around doing such a deep equality check that is linear in the size of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to try serialization with hash alongside with your value?
I mean, something like:

```js
const cache = {
  [key1]: {
    [key2]: {
      [key3]: {
        [resultValue]: { a: 5, b: 6 },
        [resultHash]: md5(JSON.stringify(val))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Browsers doesn't have any built-in hash functions API. So, get it from npmjs.org

---

UPDATE:

I may have misunderstood your question. What about this implementation?

```js
const cache = new Map()
const hash = data => btoa(JSON.stringify(data))
const hashKeys = (...keys) => keys.map(key => hash(key)).join('-')
const store = (data, ...keys) => cache[hashKeys(...keys)] = data
const load = (...keys) => cache[hashKeys(...keys)]
```

Comment: Hey @Yuri Kulagin - how does hashing the result let us do O(1) lookups in the cache?

Comment: I guess, there no right way to check that two objects are equal without passing through all they keys (JSON.stringify makes it). But we can simplify complexity by hashing something :)

Answer (score 0):

seems the most suitable data structures for your task are HashMap and Set (based on HashMap). The average time for insert and getting is O(1)
https://adrianmejia.com/data-structures-time-complexity-for-beginners-arrays-hashmaps-linked-lists-stacks-queues-tutorial